# Django and nginx - docker - problem with adding add worker_connections. nginx - directive is not allowed here

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I'm having trouble adding nginx worker connections to the config

this is my config nginx

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 10240; # increase if you have lots of clients
}
http {

  upstream my-app {
    server web-prod: 8000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-app.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml font/truetype font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # request timed out -- default 60
    client_body_timeout 10;

    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 2;

    # server will close connection after this time -- default 75
    keepalive_timeout 30;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://my-app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
      alias /usr/src/app/my-app/staticfiles/;
      expires 365d;
    }
    location /mediafiles/ {
      alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }
  }
}
```

my dockerfile nginx

```
FROM nginx:stable

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

error nginx

```
nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1
```

I guess there is a problem with my dockerfile and configuration nginx files. 
I tried many configurations and I am looking for a problem on many pages but I can't find a solution right now.
I will be grateful for the tips

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a main nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in your `/etc/nginx/` directory where the following line is present in a `http` context:

```
http {
    ...
    include  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
    ...
```

So your `worker_processes` directive goes to http context, not the main context as you might beleive. To see what is the main nginx configuration file run `nginx -V` and look at the `--conf-path=` build option value.

Comment: Im sorry but I still dont understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;

worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  10240;  ## Default: 1024
}
http {
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

my-app.conf

```
upstream my-app {
    server web-prod:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-app.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml font/truetype font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # request timed out -- default 60
    client_body_timeout 10;

    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 2;

    # server will close connection after this time -- default 75
    keepalive_timeout 30;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/my-app/staticfiles/;
        expires 365d;
    }
    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }
}
```

and my structure

[image]